# Map doesn't refresh when switching component view

Tags: angular, typescript

I integrated your map module into my angular2/typescript project. It initialised successfully. However, if I switch to another component/view, and navigate back to the map view, the map view vanishes, showing a slate of grey.

I tried the invalidateSize() trick recommended online but it didn't work for me.

Is there any other way to force the map to refresh/update?

Comment: I managed to deal with this issue by killing the map on ngOnDestroy() before leaving the map component/view. However, keep killing and recreating map on switching tab doesn't feel like a long term solution. I hope there would be a more 'proper' solution to this issue.